# Create executable bash script that accepts drag & drop

Tags: bash, ubuntu, drag-and-drop, exe

I compiled mplayer from source on Ubuntu. I didn't want to use a GUI but I wanted to make a executable bash file that gets the path from an file that gets dropped onto the bash file. How do I make such a thing possible?

I wanted to make it look something like this:
`mplayer <get full path to file`.`file-ending>`

I want the executable bash file to sit on my desktop ;)

---

If possible, I'd just like an `rightclick -> start with mplayer` function, but I don't know how to make one.

Comment: Sorry, not a programming question, voting to move to http://superuser.com/ OR you can 'flag' it and ask for a moderator to move it. (I didn't downvote your question). Good luck.

Comment: Which GUI environment are you using?

Comment: oh I'm sorry, I'm just used to posting in stackoverflow xD
I'm using gnome 3 instead of unity on ubuntu, still with lightdm.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can access arguments passed to the script with `$1` (for the first argument). And also you should make a `.desktop` file so Nautilus (or your desktop manager) know what to do and use `%u` to pass the dropped path to the script.

For example you can create a file named `DropOverMe.desktop`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Drop Over Me
Comment=Execute the script with the file dropped
Exec=gnome-terminal -e "/folder/to/the/script/launchme.sh \"%u\""
Icon=utilities-terminal
Type=Application
```

I use `gnome-terminal` as I have Ubuntu on my PC, use your preferred terminal application.

And the script could be something like:

```
#! /bin/bash

echo "Launched with $1" >> /tmp/history.log
```

Comment: You're almost 6 years late to the party. Thanks for the thorough answer though!

Comment: Thank you, just for those who come late like me ;-).

Comment: I wonder how this could be done using WSL2, which until recently was headless.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
#!/bin/bash
mplayer "$1"
```

The file path of the dropped file will be passed to the script file as the 1th command line argument.

Comment: somehow I can't drag and drop on a .sh file. The files just get piled up or copied to the desktop.

Comment: oh god finally I got it working! thanks for the code, it works! I just had to create a mplayer.desktop shortcut which starts the .sh file that can be used as a executeable. And I had to give full permissions to both files. Now it works flawless ;)

Comment: @HitomiTenshi, it would help me greatly if you could share your .desktop file contents - I'm struggling with this one.

Comment: @alfadog67, You might need ` %u` at the end on the Exec line (works for me in xfce), so it passes the args to the script.

Answer (score 1):

### In openned terminal

By using *mate-terminal*, *gnome-terminal* or *konsole*, you could use drag'n drop into oppened window.

This will send URL as tipped, with a space added, but without *endline*.

For this, run *mplayer*, I wrote this little loop function:

```
while IFS=$' \t\r\n' read -d '' -p "Wait for URL to play: " -rsn 1 str &&
    [ "$str" ];do
    while IFS= read -d '' -rsn 1 -t .02 char
    do str+="$char"
    done
    if [ "$str" ] ;then
        read -a req <<<"$str"
        echo $req
        mplayer $req
    fi
  done
```

- First read will determine if something is comming or else end loop.
- Second loop with very short timeout will read *dropped* URL as a single string
- `read -a req` will split string to consider only 1st part

Comment: Since lubuntu doesn't seem to support drag'n'drop over scripts or desktop entries, this is a nice solution for any situation where you need to quickly run something in a given app (md5sum in my case).