# How can I locate a file and use exiftool from one command line

Tags: shell, find, exiftool

I am using Linux and I'd like to be looking at a file manager window, see a file I want to remove the exif data for, then open a terminal and quickly locate the file and remove the exif data in one easy command rather than navigating to the folder first (I have long dir hierarchies and don't always know the path to them).

It seemed like this below should have worked, but it didn't.  Am I on the right track or barking up the totally wrong tree?

```
find /media -name "happy-hamster.jpg" | exiftool -all=
```

I can do this instead:

```
cd /media/typing/out/my/really/long/path/to/the/image/here/
exiftool -all= happy-hamster.jpg
```

But I'm wondering if there's an easier way:  one line, using only the filename.

Comment: If removing the EXIF data is something you do often, you could make an icon on your desktop that you just drag and drop the files onto and it can run `exiftool` on them for you... https://stackoverflow.com/a/49500317/2836621

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`find /media -name "happy-hamster.jpg" -exec exiftool -all= '{}' \;`

Answer (score 0):

*Edit:* This would be a Windows solution rather than a linux/mac solution.

Rather than go to the command line, you can use exiftool's drag/drop ability.  See [Stand-alone version in the Windows GUI](https://exiftool.org/#running).

Create a short cut to exiftool, fill the target property of the shortcut with your options (`-all=`), and then you can drag/drop the files onto the shortcut.

Alternatively, you can install something like [PathCopyCopy](https://pathcopycopy.github.io/) which will allow you to right-click a file and copy the full path to the file.  Then, instead of CDing to the directory, you can just give exiftool the full path to the file.  This works especially well in combination with a text expansion program that lets you automatically paste from the clipboard or even creating your own shortcuts with [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

Comment: I am sorry for not including that, didn't realize it wasn't clear.  I just added "I am using Linux" (I use Ubuntu and a bunch of other distros) at the beginning.  Thank you for offering the suggestion!  :-)