# Use drag and drop to populate bash scrip for awk

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I am trying to create a bash script to search for information inside an xml file. Ideally I need it to be easy to use.
Inside I want to popularize a variable from an echo and use that file path in awk but it's not working.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Enter Your path with the .xml file : " #Drag and drop the file path here

read ROUTE

if [[ -f "$ROUTE" ]]; then

    AREA=$(awk -F "[><]" '/SURFACE_AREA/{print $3}' $ROUTE)

    echo "Total area: $AREA sq. km."

else

    echo "You did not select the correct format."

fi

/bin/rm -f $AREA
/bin/rm -f $ROUTE
```

Comment: "Drag and drop" is not something that the shell has control over

Comment: @Fravadona Have a loot at [Create executable bash script that accepts drag & drop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63318233/1765658)